# Generating all random maches from lists with some exceptions

Tags: c#, list, random, match

Let's say I have five lists like these

```
  List<string> A = new List<string> {"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"};
  List<string> B = new List<string> {"B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"};
  List<string> C = new List<string> {"C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"};
  List<string> D = new List<string> {"D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5"};
  List<string> E = new List<string> {"E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5"};
```

I want to **randomly generate all possible pairs** from their elements like "A1 E2", "D4 A2" (with A1 E2 and E2 A1 being different matches) etc. etc. **BUT so that elements from lists B and C would never match.**

So I just tried doing something like this

```
  Random X = new Random();
  int rand = X.Next(1, 10); // actual range depends on number of lists

  if (rand == 1)
  Console.WriteLine(A[X.Next(A.Count)] + B[X.Next(B.Count)]) // AB match
  else if (rand == 2)
  Console.WriteLine(A[X.Next(A.Count)] + C[X.Next(C.Count)]) // AC match
  else if (rand == 3)
  Console.WriteLine(A[X.Next(A.Count)] + A[X.Next(A.Count)]) // AA match
```

And so on. Excluding BC matches. If I have a few lists it works fine. But if the number of lists grows higher this code gets too long and clumsy. **Even with 4 lists I need 14 combinations to describe!** (16 minus BC and CB). So my question is - **how do I make it shorter and more efficient?**

And question 2 - what if I want to generate not only pairs but also triples? Like "A1 B3 E5".  With exceptions (B and C) or without.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Done.

Comment: If you need all possible combinations (excluding some doesn't matter much) then don't do it randomly. Instead, do it with nested foreach loops and populate a list of combinations, that you can sort in a random order easily.

Comment: Well, excluding matters a lot for my case

Comment: I mean it doesn't matter to the principle... The point is that creating all possible combination means that it's better to first create and then sort then to create them in a random order.

Comment: Well, I can easily put all the elements into one array, then shuffle it, take a first pair, shuffle, take first pair etc. But that won't solve my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is by creating a list of all lists for the first item. Then if the first item was B then remove C from the list and randomize the second item.

Here's some sample code:

```
List<List<string>> group = new List<List<string>> { A, B, C, D, E };
Random rnd = new Random();
List<string> firstList = group[rnd.Next(group.Count)];

if (firstList == B) group.Remove(C);
else if (firstList == C) group.Remove(B);

List<string> secondList = group[rnd.Next(group.Count)];

Console.WriteLine(firstList[rnd.Next(firstList.Count)] + secondList[rnd.Next(secondList.Count)]);
```

For your second question: you can generalize the first solution with a loop and with storing the items in a result list:

```
List<List<string>> group = new List<List<string>> { A, B, C, D, E };
Random rnd = new Random();
int count = 3; //for triplets
List<string> result = new List<string>(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   List<string> row = group[rnd.Next(group.Count)];

   if (row == B) group.Remove(C);
   else if (row == C) group.Remove(B);

   result.Add(row[rnd.Next(row.Count)]);
}
foreach (string item in result)
{
     Console.Write(item);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```